# Normed vector subspace and $\epsilon$-nets

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that the closure, $\overline{V}$, of a normed vector subspace, $V$, is a vector space.

Note that the space is not necessarily complete.

To prove this statement it is easy enough to show that the closure is not equal to the empty set.

However, since I don't have that every Cauchy sequence converges how would I show that $$ ax + by \in \overline{V}$$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$ and $x,y \in \overline{V}$.

A proof I have seen uses $\epsilon$-nets. What is the intuition behind the use of an $\epsilon$-net in this case?

Comment: you don't need completeness, if $x\in \bar V$ then there is $x_n\in V$ so that $x_n\to x$. Thus, the limit of $x_n$ exists and is $x$, you don't need to deduce that the limit of $x_n$ exists invoking the fact that $x_n$ is cauchy. The same holds for $ax_n+by_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you meant that $V$ is a vector subspace of an ambient vector space, because the closure is a relative notion (the closure of $V$ in itself is always $V$).

Now:

$x\in\bar V$ if and only if $\exists x_n\in V\mid ||x_n-x||\to0$.

As $||ax_n-ax||=a||x_n-x||$, you get that $ax\in\bar V$ because $ax_n\to ax$ and $ax_n\in V$ since $V$ is a subspace of the ambient space.

Similarly, if $y\in \bar V$ then there is  $y_n\in V$ such that $y_n\to y$. As above $y_n+x_n\in V$ because $V$ is a sub-space of the ambient space. And by the triangular inequality you get 
$||y_n+x_n-(x+y)||\leq ||y_n-y||+||x_n-x||\to 0$.

Thus $\bar V$ is closed under sum an product by scalar and therefore is a subspace of the ambient space.